# Django, нумерация записей не с начала на странице

Tags: python, django

Есть примерно такая функция `def my_list(): return [x for x in range(10)]`

Цикл в шаблоне

> {% for line in my_list %}...{{ forloop.counter }}...{% endfor %}

Нужно чтобы на странице записи нумеровались не от 1 до 10, а от 50 до 60.
Как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для функции `range` можно указать дополнительные параметры:
`range(начало, конец, шаг)`
В вашем случае это будет:
`def my_list(): return [x for x in range(50, 61, 1)]`

Comment: Спасибо. А если вместо range() , у меня будет islice(f, 5, 10)?

Comment: Тоже будет работать. Если в f, например, массив [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], то islice(f, 5, 10) выдаст [5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: f - это открытый текстовый файл

Comment: Тогда из файла будут загружены 5 строк, с пятой по девятую. Если, конечно, строки в этом файле есть.

Comment: Они будут загружены, но пронумерованы на странице будут начиная с начала с 1.

Comment: Почему не сделать что-то вроде: {% for i in i_list %}
    <li>{{ i.num }}</li>
{% endfor %} , без forloop.counter?

Comment: То есть подготовить свой список ДО вывода и не пользоваться forloop.counter